# R: legend with points and lines being different colors (for the same legend item)

Tags: r, legend

Using the legend() function is it possible to have the point and line be different colors? I feel like I'm missing something fairly obvious. The `pt.bg` option can change the background color, but I'm not seeing a `pt.fg` option

The arises in the case when you use the lines() and points() command separately with different colors and want the legend to represent what is plotted.

I thought it might be possible with the `merge` options, but I clearly don't quite understand what that is for.

Example:

```
plot( 0, type="n", xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,5) )
A <- matrix( c( c(1,2,3,4), c(2,1,2,4)), ncol=2 )
B <- matrix( c( c(1,2,3,4), c(1,3,3,2)), ncol=2 )
lines( A, col="red" )
points( A, col="blue", pch=15 )
lines( B, col="green" )
points( B, col="purple", pch=17 )

legend( x="topleft", 
        legend=c("Red line, blue points","Green line, purple points"),
        col=c("red","green"), lwd=1, lty=c(1,2), 
        pch=c(15,17) )

legend( x="bottomleft", 
        legend=c("Red line","blue points","Green line","purple points"),
        col=c("red","blue","green","purple"), lwd=1, lty=c(1,NA,2,NA),
        pch=c(NA,15,NA,17) )

legend( x="left", 
        legend=c("Red line, blue points","Green line, purple points"),
        col=c("red","green"), lwd=1, lty=c(1,2), pch=c(15,17), merge=FALSE )

legend( x="bottomright", 
        legend=c("Red line","blue points","Green line","purple points"), 
        col=c("red","blue","green","purple"), lwd=1, lty=c(1,NA,2,NA), 
        pch=c(NA,15,NA,17), merge=FALSE )

legend( x="topright", 
        legend=c("Red line, blue points","Green line, purple points"), 
        col=c("red","blue","green","purple"), lwd=1, lty=c(1,2), 
        pch=c(15,17), merge=FALSE )
```

[image: IMG]

**Solution**

I hacked the legend() function to use two different color vectors:

```
LEGEND <- function (x, y = NULL, legend, fill = NULL, 
    col = par("col"), pt.col=col, line.col=col,
    border = "black", lty, lwd, pch, angle = 45, density = NULL,
    bty = "o", bg = par("bg"), box.lwd = par("lwd"), box.lty = par("lty"),
    box.col = par("fg"), pt.bg = NA, cex = 1, pt.cex = cex, pt.lwd = lwd,
    xjust = 0, yjust = 1, x.intersp = 1, y.intersp = 1, adj = c(0,
        0.5), text.width = NULL, text.col = par("col"), text.font = NULL,
    merge = do.lines && has.pch, trace = FALSE, plot = TRUE,
    ncol = 1, horiz = FALSE, title = NULL, inset = 0, xpd, title.col = text.col,
    title.adj = 0.5, seg.len = 2)
{
    if (missing(legend) && !missing(y) && (is.character(y) ||
        is.expression(y))) {
        legend <- y
        y <- NULL
    }
    mfill <- !missing(fill) || !missing(density)
    if (!missing(xpd)) {
        op <- par("xpd")
        on.exit(par(xpd = op))
        par(xpd = xpd)
    }
    title <- as.graphicsAnnot(title)
    if (length(title) > 1)
        stop("invalid 'title'")
    legend <- as.graphicsAnnot(legend)
    n.leg <- if (is.call(legend))
        1
    else length(legend)
    if (n.leg == 0)
        stop("'legend' is of length 0")
    auto <- if (is.character(x))
        match.arg(x, c("bottomright", "bottom", "bottomleft",
            "left", "topleft", "top", "topright", "right", "center"))
    else NA
    if (is.na(auto)) {
        xy <- xy.coords(x, y)
        x <- xy$x
        y <- xy$y
        nx <- length(x)
        if (nx < 1 || nx > 2)
            stop("invalid coordinate lengths")
    }
    else nx <- 0
    xlog <- par("xlog")
    ylog <- par("ylog")
    rect2 <- function(left, top, dx, dy, density = NULL, angle,
        ...) {
        r <- left + dx
        if (xlog) {
            left <- 10^left
            r <- 10^r
        }
        b <- top - dy
        if (ylog) {
            top <- 10^top
            b <- 10^b
        }
        rect(left, top, r, b, angle = angle, density = density,
            ...)
    }
    segments2 <- function(x1, y1, dx, dy, ...) {
        x2 <- x1 + dx
        if (xlog) {
            x1 <- 10^x1
            x2 <- 10^x2
        }
        y2 <- y1 + dy
        if (ylog) {
            y1 <- 10^y1
            y2 <- 10^y2
        }
        segments(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...)
    }
    points2 <- function(x, y, ...) {
        if (xlog)
            x <- 10^x
        if (ylog)
            y <- 10^y
        points(x, y, ...)
    }
    text2 <- function(x, y, ...) {
        if (xlog)
            x <- 10^x
        if (ylog)
            y <- 10^y
        text(x, y, ...)
    }
    if (trace)
        catn <- function(...) do.call("cat", c(lapply(list(...),
            formatC), list("\n")))
    cin <- par("cin")
    Cex <- cex * par("cex")
    if (is.null(text.width))
        text.width <- max(abs(strwidth(legend, units = "user",
            cex = cex, font = text.font)))
    else if (!is.numeric(text.width) || text.width < 0)
        stop("'text.width' must be numeric, >= 0")
    xc <- Cex * xinch(cin[1L], warn.log = FALSE)
    yc <- Cex * yinch(cin[2L], warn.log = FALSE)
    if (xc < 0)
        text.width <- -text.width
    xchar <- xc
    xextra <- 0
    yextra <- yc * (y.intersp - 1)
    ymax <- yc * max(1, strheight(legend, units = "user", cex = cex)/yc)
    ychar <- yextra + ymax
    if (trace)
        catn("  xchar=", xchar, "; (yextra,ychar)=", c(yextra,
            ychar))
    if (mfill) {
        xbox <- xc * 0.8
        ybox <- yc * 0.5
        dx.fill <- xbox
    }
    do.lines <- (!missing(lty) && (is.character(lty) || any(lty >
        0))) || !missing(lwd)
    n.legpercol <- if (horiz) {
        if (ncol != 1)
            warning(gettextf("horizontal specification overrides: Number of columns := %d",
                n.leg), domain = NA)
        ncol <- n.leg
        1
    }
    else ceiling(n.leg/ncol)
    has.pch <- !missing(pch) && length(pch) > 0
    if (do.lines) {
        x.off <- if (merge)
            -0.7
        else 0
    }
    else if (merge)
        warning("'merge = TRUE' has no effect when no line segments are drawn")
    if (has.pch) {
        if (is.character(pch) && !is.na(pch[1L]) && nchar(pch[1L],
            type = "c") > 1) {
            if (length(pch) > 1)
                warning("not using pch[2..] since pch[1L] has multiple chars")
            np <- nchar(pch[1L], type = "c")
            pch <- substr(rep.int(pch[1L], np), 1L:np, 1L:np)
        }
        if (!is.character(pch))
            pch <- as.integer(pch)
    }
    if (is.na(auto)) {
        if (xlog)
            x <- log10(x)
        if (ylog)
            y <- log10(y)
    }
    if (nx == 2) {
        x <- sort(x)
        y <- sort(y)
        left <- x[1L]
        top <- y[2L]
        w <- diff(x)
        h <- diff(y)
        w0 <- w/ncol
        x <- mean(x)
        y <- mean(y)
        if (missing(xjust))
            xjust <- 0.5
        if (missing(yjust))
            yjust <- 0.5
    }
    else {
        h <- (n.legpercol + (!is.null(title))) * ychar + yc
        w0 <- text.width + (x.intersp + 1) * xchar
        if (mfill)
            w0 <- w0 + dx.fill
        if (do.lines)
            w0 <- w0 + (seg.len + x.off) * xchar
        w <- ncol * w0 + 0.5 * xchar
        if (!is.null(title) && (abs(tw <- strwidth(title, units = "user",
            cex = cex) + 0.5 * xchar)) > abs(w)) {
            xextra <- (tw - w)/2
            w <- tw
        }
        if (is.na(auto)) {
            left <- x - xjust * w
            top <- y + (1 - yjust) * h
        }
        else {
            usr <- par("usr")
            inset <- rep_len(inset, 2)
            insetx <- inset[1L] * (usr[2L] - usr[1L])
            left <- switch(auto, bottomright = , topright = ,
                right = usr[2L] - w - insetx, bottomleft = ,
                left = , topleft = usr[1L] + insetx, bottom = ,
                top = , center = (usr[1L] + usr[2L] - w)/2)
            insety <- inset[2L] * (usr[4L] - usr[3L])
            top <- switch(auto, bottomright = , bottom = , bottomleft = usr[3L] +
                h + insety, topleft = , top = , topright = usr[4L] -
                insety, left = , right = , center = (usr[3L] +
                usr[4L] + h)/2)
        }
    }
    if (plot && bty != "n") {
        if (trace)
            catn("  rect2(", left, ",", top, ", w=", w, ", h=",
                h, ", ...)", sep = "")
        rect2(left, top, dx = w, dy = h, col = bg, density = NULL,
            lwd = box.lwd, lty = box.lty, border = box.col)
    }
    xt <- left + xchar + xextra + (w0 * rep.int(0:(ncol - 1),
        rep.int(n.legpercol, ncol)))[1L:n.leg]
    yt <- top - 0.5 * yextra - ymax - (rep.int(1L:n.legpercol,
        ncol)[1L:n.leg] - 1 + (!is.null(title))) * ychar
    if (mfill) {
        if (plot) {
            if (!is.null(fill))
                fill <- rep_len(fill, n.leg)
            rect2(left = xt, top = yt + ybox/2, dx = xbox, dy = ybox,
                col = fill, density = density, angle = angle,
                border = border)
        }
        xt <- xt + dx.fill
    }
    if (plot && (has.pch || do.lines)) {
        pt.COL <- rep_len(pt.col, n.leg)
        line.COL <- rep_len(line.col, n.leg)
    }
    if (missing(lwd) || is.null(lwd))
        lwd <- par("lwd")
    if (do.lines) {
        if (missing(lty) || is.null(lty))
            lty <- 1
        lty <- rep_len(lty, n.leg)
        lwd <- rep_len(lwd, n.leg)
        ok.l <- !is.na(lty) & (is.character(lty) | lty > 0) &
            !is.na(lwd)
        if (trace)
            catn("  segments2(", xt[ok.l] + x.off * xchar, ",",
                yt[ok.l], ", dx=", seg.len * xchar, ", dy=0, ...)")
        if (plot)
            segments2(xt[ok.l] + x.off * xchar, yt[ok.l], dx = seg.len *
                xchar, dy = 0, lty = lty[ok.l], lwd = lwd[ok.l],
                col = line.COL[ok.l])
        xt <- xt + (seg.len + x.off) * xchar
    }
    if (has.pch) {
        pch <- rep_len(pch, n.leg)
        pt.bg <- rep_len(pt.bg, n.leg)
        pt.cex <- rep_len(pt.cex, n.leg)
        pt.lwd <- rep_len(pt.lwd, n.leg)
        ok <- !is.na(pch)
        if (!is.character(pch)) {
            ok <- ok & (pch >= 0 | pch <= -32)
        }
        else {
            ok <- ok & nzchar(pch)
        }
        x1 <- (if (merge && do.lines)
            xt - (seg.len/2) * xchar
        else xt)[ok]
        y1 <- yt[ok]
        if (trace)
            catn("  points2(", x1, ",", y1, ", pch=", pch[ok],
                ", ...)")
        if (plot)
            points2(x1, y1, pch = pch[ok], col = pt.COL[ok], cex = pt.cex[ok],
                bg = pt.bg[ok], lwd = pt.lwd[ok])
    }
    xt <- xt + x.intersp * xchar
    if (plot) {
        if (!is.null(title))
            text2(left + w * title.adj, top - ymax, labels = title,
                adj = c(title.adj, 0), cex = cex, col = title.col)
        text2(xt, yt, labels = legend, adj = adj, cex = cex,
            col = text.col, font = text.font)
    }
    invisible(list(rect = list(w = w, h = h, left = left, top = top),
        text = list(x = xt, y = yt)))
}
```

And used as follows:

```
LEGEND( x="bottomleft", 
        legend=c("Red line, blue points","Green line, purple points"),
        col=c("red","green"), 
        lwd=1, lty=c(1,2), pch=c(15,17) )

LEGEND( x="bottomright", 
        legend=c("Red line, blue points","Green line, purple points"),
        pt.col=c("blue","purple"), line.col=c("red","green"),
        lwd=1, lty=c(1,2), pch=c(15,17) )
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're going to have to hack/roll your own ...

Comment: Awesome! Post it as an answer. I didn't see your solution. It worked perfect for me, even for horizontal legends

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this with 2 calls to `legend`, the 1st time plots the lines, then the second call plots over the top with invisible lines, but plots the points in the desired colors:

```
plot( 0, type="n", xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,5) )
A <- matrix( c( c(1,2,3,4), c(2,1,2,4)), ncol=2 )
B <- matrix( c( c(1,2,3,4), c(1,3,3,2)), ncol=2 )
lines( A, col="red" )
points( A, col="blue", pch=15 )
lines( B, col="green" )
points( B, col="purple", pch=17 )

legend( x="topleft", 
        legend=c("Red line, blue points","Green line, purple points"),
        col=c("red","green"), lwd=1, lty=c(1,2), 
        pch=c(NA,NA) )

legend( x="topleft", 
        legend=c("Red line, blue points","Green line, purple points"),
        col=c("blue","purple"), lwd=1, lty=c(0,0), 
        pch=c(15,17) )
```

or for the second call to `legend` you can do something like this (so you don't have 2 copies of the text on top of each other):

```
legend( x="topleft", 
        legend=c("",""),
        col=c("blue","purple"), lwd=1, lty=c(0,0), 
        pch=c(15,17), bty='n' )
```

Of course this only lines up properly working from the left.  If you want the plot in one of the right corners then save the return value from the first call to `legend` and use it for placement in the second call.

Comment: The last suggestion to avoid 2 copies of text being printed on top of each other only works for "left" aligned legends. Another trick would be to use the `text.col` option, which would also work for "right" aligned legends. Use `text.col = "white"` in the first and `text.col = "black"` in the second call to `legend`.

Comment: It didn't work either for horizontally aligned legends. @Simon posted his own solution (modify the legend function itself) in the question and it worked perfect for me.