# Add legend to multiple time-series plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, legend

I have two time series data that I want to show on the same graph.
Both series have three columns: Date, County and Value.
Here is my code:

```
#Data
Series1 <- data.frame(Date = c(2000,2001,2000,2001), County = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),Total = c(100,150,190,130))
Series2 <- data.frame(Date = c(2000,2001,2000,2001), County = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),Total = c(180,120,140,120))

#Plot data
ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data = Series1, aes(x = Date, y = Total, color = County), linetype="solid") +
    geom_line(data = Series2, aes(x = Date, y = Total, color = County), linetype="dashed")
```

The plot looks like this:

[image: plot]

Now I just need to add one legend showing that solid line represents Series1 and dashed line represents Series2. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: changing-the-line-type-in-the-ggplot-legend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875582/changing-the-line-type-in-the-ggplot-legend)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: legend with points and lines being different colors (for the same legend item)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053440/r-legend-with-points-and-lines-being-different-colors-for-the-same-legend-item)

Comment: @PereG I tried    +scale_linetype_manual("Type",values=c("solid"=2,"dashed"=1)), but nothing happen.

Comment: @Sean if you provide a minimum reproducible example, it would be much easier to help

Comment: @PereG I added a small subset of my data as example, hope it will help. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legends are created automatically when you use `aes()` to map a data column to an aesthetic. You don't have a data column that you're mapping to the linetype aesthetic, so we need to create one.

```
Series1$series = 1
Series2$series = 2
all_series = rbind(Series1, Series2)
```

Now we've all the data together and plotting is easy:

```
ggplot(all_series,
       aes(x = Date, y = Total, color = County, linetype = factor(series))) + 
    geom_line()
```

Automatic legend, only one `geom_line` call, using `ggplot` as it's meant to be used: with tidy data.

Comment: I agree with Gregor that the right thing is to manipulate the data previously.

Comment: Thank you both @PereG@Gregor. It works well. My follow-up question is: When I made a bunch of figures, sometimes the "County" legend box comes first and sometimes the "Series" legend box does. Is there a way to make them consistent?

Comment: Explicitly define it using an `order` argument to `guide_legend` as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11397958/903061. And do make a habit of searching for answers before asking. This was the first hit searching  Stack Overflow for "ggplot2 order legends".

Answer (score 1):

You are really close...

```
ggplot() + 
      geom_line(data = Series1, aes(x = Date, y = Total, color = County), linetype="solid") +
      geom_line(data = Series2, aes(x = Date, y = Total, color = County), linetype="dashed")+ scale_linetype_manual()
```

[image]